# Tkinter Entry widget float number

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.4

I'm making a BMI calculator just to get my head around tkinter. I am stuck on this one part- how do I make it so it gets a float number from the entry widget?

Here are some snippets of my code

Getting entry inputs (this is in a function called calculateBMI)

```
hgtval = float(height.get())
wgtval = float(weight.get())
```

Here is creating the variables and making the entry boxes.

```
hgt = StringVar()
wgt = StringVar()

height = Entry(root, stringvariable=hgt).grid(row=1, column=2)
weight = Entry(root, stringvariable=wgt).grid(row=2, column=2)
```

Running the whole program I am given this error:

```
C:\Python34\python.exe I:/programming/project/bmi.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "I:/programming/project/bmi.py", line 35, in <module>
    height = Entry(root, stringvariable=hgt).grid(row=1, column=2)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2478, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'entry', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2086, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-stringvariable"
```

Comment: It should be `textvariable` not `stringvariable`. See [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm).

Comment: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option is `textvariable`, not `stringvariable`.

Unrelated to this problem, when you do `height = Entry(...).grid(...)`, `height` will always be `None` since that is what `.grid(...)` returns. It is a best practice to separate widget creation from widget layout.

When you do that (separating creation from layout) you don't actually  need to use `StringVar`s, since you can get the value directly from the widget itself (eg: `hgtval = float(height.get())`